# Mostrar un error al utilizar un filtro en una búsqueda

Tags: laravel-5

quisiera de su ayuda, he colocado un search en mi vista, pero si alguien ingresa un valor que no existe me despliega un error, cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje que le diga al usuario, que ese valor no existe

les dejo parte del código

public function search(Request $request)
    {

```
    $deposito = Deposito::where('noboleta','like','%'.$request->noboleta.'%')->first();
    return view('depositos.show',compact('deposito'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta consulta solo te devolverá un registro; si quieres que sean todos los que encuentre debes cambiar `first()` por `get()`.

```
$deposito = Deposito::where('noboleta', 'like', '%' . $request->noboleta . '%')->first();
```

En cualquier caso, si no encuentra ninguno, lo que hay que hacer es comprobar que no hay registros y volver a la página original informando que no se ha encontrado ninguno.

```
if (! $deposito) {
    return \Redirect::back()->with('flash_error', 'No se ha encontrado');
}
```

Y si se ha encontrado al menos uno, devolver la vista en la que lo mostrarás.

```
return view('depositos.show', compact('deposito'));
```